# How to receive email in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, pop3

Is it possible to develop a system in codeigniter that is capable of receiving reply of emails as well. 
Actually I want to develop email receiving feature in codeigniter . 
Please guide with complete detail considering me at beiginner level. 
Thanks

Comment: They have a email helper here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html But this is not a suitable question on here.

Answer (score 2):

This involves developing a mail client application. Maybe you will search the web where you will find some open source application that you then should integrate with codeigniter.

Her is a video which can help you to get started:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-OweUqMPsY

**EDIT:**

This process is not so simple as you can think but if you download this code you can have a directly inside on what and how you can do it:

https://github.com/Studio182/Crystal-Mail

Comment: Thanks @Franco , this is exactly what I am looking for . but can you please guide me how to develop this . In the video you mentioned I don t find any development guidance.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, and if you think that this has been useful for you and could be for others accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try following libraries or code to receive emails:

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/IMAP

also you can user:

https://garrettstjohn.com/article/reading-emails-with-php/
https://garrettstjohn.com/article/extracting-attachments-from-emails-with-php/

hope these will help you build your app.